# Getting 404 for vimeo api even though the video is available?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api, oembed

I've been working around the oembed response of two videos.

1. https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?callback=vimeoCallback&url=https://vimeo.com/392817533
2. https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?callback=vimeoCallback&url=https://vimeo.com/360905947

First one works perfect fine. But I'm getting a 404 for the second. The second video is available at https://player.vimeo.com/video/360905947. Why the oembed returns 404, could somebody help resolving this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue? I'm experiencing the same thing. Interestingly I can load the oembed URL directl8yin the browser and get the json response, so not sure why the vimeo player object can't retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things could be happening here, but I think the most likely issue is that you did not encode the URL of the video you're embedding.

I tested with both of your videos and was able to get successful responses like so:

```
https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=https%3a%2f%2fvimeo.com%2f392817533
```

and

```
https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=https%3a%2f%2fvimeo.com%2f360905947
```

Check out more from their documentation here:
[Vimeo Developer Documentation](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/oembed/videos)

A noteworthy part of that page for others experiencing 404 errors is the "Handling errors" section where you'll see:

| Http Status Code | Probable cause |
| --- | --- |
| 404 | You aren't able to access the video because of privacy or permissions issues, or because the video is still transcoding. |

This means the person who uploaded may have turned on a privacy setting which is blocking the oembed service from working. If possible, you could reach out to the owner and see if they are willing to update the video's privacy settings.